# if condition in shell scripting based on 404 unauthorized error

Tags: shell, curl

Here is my shell script. I want to put a condition to my curl commands based on the status i get. I need help in grepping "Http/1.1 401 Unauthorized" from the first curl command. After that i need to put it in a condition if status is 401, execute 2nd and 3rd curl command. Pls help

```
STATUS="HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"
read $STATUS

for ((i=1; i<=2000; i++)); do
curl -i -vs -X POST -D post.txt -H "$SESSION_TOKEN" -H "$AUTH_TOKEN" -H "Accept:$ACCEPT_HEADER" -H "Content-Type:text/plain" "http://$BASE_URI/api/$PLATFORM//$CHANNEL_ID/subscription" | grep -e "*Unauth*" >> post.txt

if [$STATUS]
then
curl -i -vs -X POST -D tmp.txt -H "Content-Type:text/plain" --data "$SECRET" -H "Accept:$ACCEPT_HEADER" -H "Connection:close" http://$BASE_URI/api/${PLATFORM}/authenticate >> tmp1.txt
SESSION_TOKEN=`grep SessionToken tmp.txt`

curl -i -vs -X POST -D tmp2.txt -H "$SESSION_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data "{ \"username\":\"$USER_NAME\",\"password\":\"$PASSWORD\", \"rememberMe\":\"false\"}" http://$BASE_URI/api/web/users/authenticate >> data.json
AUTH_TOKEN=`grep Authorization tmp2.txt`

continue

fi

done
```

Comment: "*Unath*" will solve the problem ANubhav?

Comment: What do you think this line does? `read $STATUS`

Comment: definitely not. The shell sees this: `read HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` -- the shell will stop and wait to read a line of input, and then emit the error "bash: read: 'HTTP/1.1': not a valid identifier"

Comment: can u pls help me how can i proceed.. i am stuck.

Comment: remove that line, and carefully read sputnick's answer

Comment: i hope u saw my script.. how do u suggest me to make change in that..

Answer (score 4):

The proper solution :

```
res=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' http://google.fr)
if ((res == 404)); then
    echo "404 spotted"
fi
```

or

```
res=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' http://google.fr)
if [[ $res == 404 ]]; then
    echo "404 spotted"
fi
```

Check

```
man curl | less +/'^ *-w'
```

Comment: i am passing it like this.. pls correct me if its not correct.

Comment: for ((i=1; i<=1000; i++)); do

res=$(curl -v -s -o /dev/null -w `%{http_code}\n` -X POST -H "$SESSION_TOKEN" -H "$AUTH_TOKEN" -H "Accept:$ACCEPT_HEADER" -H "Content-Type:text/plain" "http://$BASE_URI/api/subscription") >> data.json | grep -e "*Unauthorized"  >> RESULT.txt

if [[ $res == 401 ]]
then

Comment: No. `res=$(curl -v -s -o data.json -w %{http_code}\n -X POST -H "$SESSION_TOKEN" -H "$AUTH_TOKEN" -H "Accept:$ACCEPT_HEADER" -H "Content-Type:text/plain" "http://$BASE_URI/api/subscription"); [[ $res == 401 ]] && ...`

Comment: its not working. infact after 30 mins session token expires and i am capturing it and should renew it. but its not getting renewed and simply throwing 401 error :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the curl output and examine the status line:

```
output=$( curl -i ... )

if [[ $output == "$STATUS"* ]]; then
    # I was unauthorized
else
    # ...
fi
```

---

Be aware that `[` (and `[[` I use in my answer) 
is not mere syntax, it is a command, and as such it requires a space between it and its arguments